# Cancel DELETE with TRIGGERs

Tags: mysql, triggers, abort

I want to cancel a TRIGGER of DELETE. The idea is BEFORE DELETE, set column `hide = "Y"` then CANCEL the TRIGGER event and NOT really DELETE the row.

It's possible?

Comment: If MySQL supported `INSTEAD OF` triggers, this would definitely be possible.  But unless something's changed I don't believe it supports that at this time.

Comment: Sounds like something that should be handled by business logic instead of database magic.

Comment: Yeah... Generally I do it on PHP (I'll), but I read about INSTEAD OF thing but I not found it for MYSQL. :( Seems that have a workarround for that, only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cancel the delete, however you cannot change the values in a `DELETE` trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bd_t1_each BEFORE DELETE ON t1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  //This will not work, because the `NEW` virtual table does not exist in a delete trigger.
  SET NEW.hide = 'Y';
  //Raising an error will work.
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DELETE canceled'; 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Instead you should make a stored procedure to *hide* your rows:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE delete_t1_row (pID INTEGER)
BEGIN
  UPDATE t1 SET hide = 'Y' WHERE id = pID;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't solve the problem, but explain that it's impossible currently. Maybe a MySQL limitation...